# Doc-type html/w3c breaks css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is a question that has likely been asked a thousand times but I cannot understand why this isn't working.

This webpage displays perfectly fine without a doc-type declaration but as soon as I add a doc-type to the page it breaks the css for the navbar.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

url: http://www2.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ob10/Home.html

Comment: Your link seems broken. I get redirected to Chrome website?! Also tell us which doctypes you want and what you have tried. We need to see the code.
Rob also have a pretty nice answer.

Comment: @SimonJensen Link worked for me.

Comment: I need it do be xhtml compliant but for now I just need the navbar or any other things that are broken by adding a doc-type to function properly.

Answer (score 2):

[A doctype is required on all web pages.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#the-doctype) Without one, you are in "quirks mode" where it's like it was 1999 all over again and you never want to be there. Quirks mode is the incorrect version of the box model which Microsoft and Internet Explorer screwed up years ago. The sole purpose of the doctype is to set your browser into "standards mode".

[Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/)

> In the Quirks mode the browsers violate contemporary Web format
>   specifications in order to avoid “breaking” pages authored according
>   to practices that were prevalent in the late 1990s. Previously,
>   different browsers implemented different quirks. In particular, in
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 and 9, the Quirks mode is effectively frozen
>   IE 5.5, while in other browsers the Quirks mode has been a handful of
>   deviations from the Almost Standards mode.

Comment: Okay so specifically for the nav bar, how would I get it to display as normal?

Comment: @Eidolon Step 1: Add the doctype to get into standards mode. Step 2: Redo your CSS to reflect any changes to your navbar and the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I was having is that in quirks mode some browsers allow for weak typing of html attributes, whereas that is not allowed in standards mode.

E.G

```
 .topNav{/*some style*/}
```

could be applied in quirks mode with: 
`<div class="topnav">`

but in standards mode: `<div class="topNav">` is required.

Comment: That doesn't make sense so you're going to have to explain. Especially where you came up with "loose typing".